# Двойная буферизация не сохраняет промежуточную картинку.

Tags: windows, gdi, c#, winforms, graphics

Пишу графический редактор на С# в WinForms. Для рисования фигур использую двойную буферизацию. Вот код функции:

```
 private void DrawFigure( int x, int y) {

            Graphics g = PicPole.CreateGraphics();

            BufferedGraphicsContext currentContext;
            BufferedGraphics myBuffer;
            currentContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;

            myBuffer = currentContext.Allocate(g,
               this.DisplayRectangle);

            myBuffer.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(ob.Paintcolor), ob.X, ob.Y, x - ob.X, y - ob.Y);

            myBuffer.Render(g);    
        }
```

PicPole - это PictureBox. 
Проблема заключается в том, что при каждом вызове этой функции(DrawFigure) **очищается весь  PictureBox и заливается чёрным цветом(т.е. отображается только текущий эллипс, а все предыдущие очищаются)**, а мне нужно, что бы изображение не очищалось, а просто дорисовывался новый эллипс. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что вы при каждом вызове *DrawFigure* создаёте новый *Graphics*. Попробуйте перенести строку *g = PicPole.CreateGraphics()* в событие *FormLoad*, предварительно объявив *g* как переменную класса формы.